# Subversion: Wrong global-ignores / can't see mime-types

Tags: svn, mime-type, revision-control

I'm currently testing Subversion on a Server. As you can see in my config file below, I did following edits:

***A***:  I added global ignores:

```
global-ignores = *thumb.db *.tmp
```

***B***:  I enabled auto-props and added some extensions to be set as a specific mime-type:

```
enable-auto-props = yes

*.rtf = svn:mime-type=application/rtf

...

* = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream
```

As you can see, I want everything binary except of the defined ones.

**My problems**

***A***:  In Tortoise it shows me the following:

[image]

But I didn't define these global ignores! **How can I do that it reads them from my config file?**

When I click on "Edit", it opens my config file.

***B***:  When I want to check the mime types, it doesn't show me anything:

```
G:\csmdepot_newtags_edited_config\csmdepot>svn proplist 

CSMVersion.iniG:\csmdepot_newtags_edited_config\csmdepot>
```

The same thing happens with Tortoise, it doesn't show me any properties:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wreyxv1.png]

**What can I do to see the mime-types of my files?**

Here my config file:

```
 ### This file configures various client-side behaviors.
###
### The commented-out examples below are intended to demonstrate
### how to use this file.

### Section for authentication and authorization customizations.
[auth]
### Set password stores used by Subversion. They should be
### delimited by spaces or commas. The order of values determines
### the order in which password stores are used.
### Valid password stores:
###   gnome-keyring        (Unix-like systems)
###   kwallet              (Unix-like systems)
###   keychain             (Mac OS X)
###   windows-cryptoapi    (Windows)
# password-stores = windows-cryptoapi
### To disable all password stores, use an empty list:
# password-stores =
###
### The rest of the [auth] section in this file has been deprecated.
### Both 'store-passwords' and 'store-auth-creds' can now be
### specified in the 'servers' file in your config directory
### and are documented there. Anything specified in this section 
### is overridden by settings specified in the 'servers' file.
# store-passwords = no
# store-auth-creds = no

### Section for configuring external helper applications.
[helpers]
### Set editor-cmd to the command used to invoke your text editor.
###   This will override the environment variables that Subversion
###   examines by default to find this information ($EDITOR, 
###   et al).
# editor-cmd = editor (vi, emacs, notepad, etc.)
### Set diff-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff implementation.
# diff-cmd = diff_program (diff, gdiff, etc.)
### Diff-extensions are arguments passed to an external diff
### program or to Subversion's internal diff implementation.
### Set diff-extensions to override the default arguments ('-u').
# diff-extensions = -u -p
### Set diff3-cmd to the absolute path of your 'diff3' program.
###   This will override the compile-time default, which is to use
###   Subversion's internal diff3 implementation.
# diff3-cmd = diff3_program (diff3, gdiff3, etc.)
### Set diff3-has-program-arg to 'yes' if your 'diff3' program
###   accepts the '--diff-program' option.
# diff3-has-program-arg = [yes | no]
### Set merge-tool-cmd to the command used to invoke your external
### merging tool of choice. Subversion will pass 5 arguments to
### the specified command: base theirs mine merged wcfile
# merge-tool-cmd = merge_command

### Section for configuring tunnel agents.
[tunnels]
### Configure svn protocol tunnel schemes here.  By default, only
### the 'ssh' scheme is defined.  You can define other schemes to
### be used with 'svn+scheme://hostname/path' URLs.  A scheme
### definition is simply a command, optionally prefixed by an
### environment variable name which can override the command if it
### is defined.  The command (or environment variable) may contain
### arguments, using standard shell quoting for arguments with
### spaces.  The command will be invoked as:
###   <command> <hostname> svnserve -t
### (If the URL includes a username, then the hostname will be
### passed to the tunnel agent as <user>@<hostname>.)  If the
### built-in ssh scheme were not predefined, it could be defined
### as:
# ssh = $SVN_SSH ssh -q
### If you wanted to define a new 'rsh' scheme, to be used with
### 'svn+rsh:' URLs, you could do so as follows:
# rsh = rsh
### Or, if you wanted to specify a full path and arguments:
# rsh = /path/to/rsh -l myusername
### On Windows, if you are specifying a full path to a command,
### use a forward slash (/) or a paired backslash (\\) as the
### path separator.  A single backslash will be treated as an
### escape for the following character.

### Section for configuring miscelleneous Subversion options.
[miscellany]
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
### '*' matches leading dots, e.g. '*.rej' matches '.foo.rej'.
global-ignores = *thumb.db *.tmp
#   *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
### Set log-encoding to the default encoding for log messages
# log-encoding = latin1
### Set use-commit-times to make checkout/update/switch/revert
### put last-committed timestamps on every file touched.
# use-commit-times = yes
### Set no-unlock to prevent 'svn commit' from automatically
### releasing locks on files.
# no-unlock = yes
### Set mime-types-file to a MIME type registry file, used to
### provide hints to Subversion's MIME type auto-detection
### algorithm.
# mime-types-file = /path/to/mime.types
### Set preserved-conflict-file-exts to a whitespace-delimited
### list of patterns matching file extensions which should be
### preserved in generated conflict file names.  By default,
### conflict files use custom extensions.
# preserved-conflict-file-exts = doc ppt xls od?
### Set enable-auto-props to 'yes' to enable automatic properties
### for 'svn add' and 'svn import', it defaults to 'no'.
### Automatic properties are defined in the section 'auto-props'.
enable-auto-props = yes
### Set interactive-conflicts to 'no' to disable interactive
### conflict resolution prompting.  It defaults to 'yes'.
# interactive-conflicts = no
### Set memory-cache-size to define the size of the memory cache
### used by the client when accessing a FSFS repository via
### ra_local (the file:// scheme). The value represents the number
### of MB used by the cache.
# memory-cache-size = 16

### Section for configuring automatic properties.
[auto-props]
### The format of the entries is:
###   file-name-pattern = propname[=value][;propname[=value]...]
### The file-name-pattern can contain wildcards (such as '*' and
### '?').  All entries which match (case-insensitively) will be
### applied to the file.  Note that auto-props functionality
### must be enabled, which is typically done by setting the
### 'enable-auto-props' option.
# *.c = svn:eol-style=native
# *.cpp = svn:eol-style=native
# *.h = svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev URL;svn:eol-style=native
# *.dsp = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.dsw = svn:eol-style=CRLF
# *.sh = svn:eol-style=native;svn:executable
# *.txt = svn:eol-style=native;svn:keywords=Author Date Id Rev URL;
*.rtf = svn:mime-type=application/rtf
*.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg
*.png = svn:mime-type=image/png
*.gif = svn:mime-type=image/gif
*.xml = svn:mime-type=text/xml
*.html = svn:mime-type=text/html
*.txt = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.ini = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.vbs = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.cmd = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.bat = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.ps1 = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.wsf = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.cfg = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.inf = svn:mime-type=text/plain
*.config = svn:mime-type=text/plain
* = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You <strike>have</strike>must to understand some things

- when you change *anything* in %APPDATA\Subversion\config, you change behavior of **Subversion client** on interacting with **all and any repositories** with *this host*'s svn client, runnging by *this user*
- these changes are local and they are not copied|stored on server side (to some degree), different clients for the same repo may have different (and even incompatible) settings
- TortoiseSVN have own additional settings on top of system defaults, but **use** global settings also
- Autoproperties in Subversion define additional properties, which will be added to files on first commit into repo (after `svn add`), f you want to test auto-props, you have to commit into repository any file, for which these properties have to be applied and verify results for *files in question only* (in your case, if you use proplist inside WC /I can't see target in command/, you have to use -R /recursive/ fkag in ordfer to list all objects in tree, directory itself can't have mime-type)
- "*" is invalid filename-pattern (for Windows), and for this reason your ini haven't redefined mime-type (try *.*, but I can't predict mime/type for specially defined extensions)